# Can't Invoke EventHandler

Tags: c#, wcf, events, windows-phone-8, event-handling

Hi I 've an WCF Service Method named GetString, I've to call it Windows Phone App, For that I'm using a EventHandler that cant be invoked.. Here is my sample code,

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MobileService1.Service1Client x = new MobileService1.Service1Client();
        x.GetStringAsync();
        x.GetStringCompleted += new EventHandler<MobileService1.GetStringCompletedEventArgs>(x_GetStringCompleted);
    }

 private void x_GetStringCompleted(object sender, MobileService1.GetStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
    }
```

This **x_GetStringCompleted** is not invoked, Plz help Folks...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a local variable for your service. Presumably the call to the service isn't done before the end of the Button_Click_1 method. So your service instance and therefore the completed delegate might be gone before the async call has finished.